# Problem in installing security updates and recommended updates using update manager

Tags: 11.04, update-manager

I installed UBUNTU 11.04 just few days before. Then when I tried to install the packages from  update manager,I got the following message.

```
*****installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
 Extracting templates from packages: 93%% Extracting templates from packages: 100%%
Preconfiguring packages ...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
 Extracting templates from packages: 93%% Extracting templates from packages: 100%%
Preconfiguring packages ...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
 Extracting templates from packages: 93%% Extracting templates from packages: 100%%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ...  (Reading database ... 5%% (Reading database ... 10%% (Reading database ... 15%% (Reading database ... 20%% (Reading database ... 25%% (Reading database ... 30%% (Reading database ... 35%% (Reading database ... 40%% (Reading database ... 45%% (Reading database ... 50%% (Reading database ... 55%% (Reading database ... 60%% (Reading database ... 65%% (Reading database ... 70%% (Reading database ... 75%% (Reading database ... 80%% (Reading database ... 85%% (Reading database ... 90%% (Reading database ... 95%% (Reading database ... 100%% (Reading database ... 157111 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace ubuntu-docs 11.04.2 (using .../ubuntu-docs_11.04.3_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement ubuntu-docs ...
dpkg: ../../src/archives.c:968: tarobject: Assertion `r == stab.st_size' failed.*****
```

This is also preventing me from installing from ubuntu software center. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was a problem with your package manager, there is a description of all the steps to solve this on [launchpad.net](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/168976).

Follow those and you should have a working system.